# How to remove all not single files Linux directory?

Tags: linux, bash, rm

I have duplicated files in directory on Linux machine which are listed like that:

```
ltulikowski@lukasz-pc:~$ ls -1
abcd
abcd.1
abcd.2
abdc
abdc.1
acbd
```

I want to remove all files witch aren't single so as a result I should have:

```
ltulikowski@lukasz-pc:~$ ls -1
acbd
```

Comment: Remove all files which aren't single...? what does this mean ?

Comment: If a file has  a duplicate it should be removed. All duplicates of the file also. should be removed

Comment: What if abcd.1 exist but abcd does not. Would you like to remove abcd.1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function uses *extglob*, so before execution, set *extglob*: `shopt -s extglob`

```
rm_if_dup_exist(){ 
    arr=()
    for file in *.+([0-9]);do
        base=${file%.*};
        if [[ -e $base ]]; then
            arr+=("$base" "$file")
        fi
    done
    rm -f -- "${arr[@]}"
}
```

This will also support file names with several digits after the `.` e.g. abcd.**250** is also acceptable.

---

**Usage example with your input:**

```
$ touch abcd abcd.1 abcd.2 abdc abdc.1 acbd
$ rm_if_dup_exist
$ ls
  acbd
```

---

Please notice that if, for example, **abcd.1** exist but **abcd** does not exist, it won't delete **abcd.1**.

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it

```
for f in *.[0-9]; do rm ${f%.*}*; done
```

may get exceptions since some files will be deleted more than once (abcd in your example).  If versions always start with .1 you can restrict to match to that.

Comment: It will remove all files in this particular example.

Comment: nope, only the ones with same named files with extensions.

Comment: To remove the duplicates, you can pipe it through `sort` and `uniq`: `for f in $(for f in *.[0-9]; do echo "${f%.*}; done | sort | uniq); do rm ${f}*; done`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
while read -r f; do
   rm "$f"*
done < <(printf "%s\n" * | cut -d. -f1 | uniq -d)
```

`printf`, `cut` and `uniq` are used to get duplicate entries (part before dot) in current directory.

Answer (score -3):

The command

```
 rm *.*
```

Should do the trick if I understand you correctly

Use `ls` to confirm first